# How to keep previous data when refetching multiple times using React Query?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, caching, react-query, ajax-polling

I've implemented a custom React hook creates a task on my API, stores the task UUID in state and then starts polling the API every 2 seconds until successful data is received.

The problem I'm facing is that I want to display the *last successful data* returned from the API while it's fetching or refetching for new data. Right now the query result is `undefined` when `mutate` is called. I don't want that.

The API is slow right now and it takes about *12 seconds or 6 refetches* to complete the request successfully, so I want to display the old data meanwhile. I think you understand what I'm trying to say by now.

You can ignore the `sendToBackground()`, it's how you communicate with background service workers using Plasmo.

**Tools I'm using:**

- Plasmo 0.81.0
- React 18.2.0
- React Query ^3.39.3

### `use-suggestions.ts`

```
export function useSuggestions(
  text: string,
  id: string,
): UseQueryResult<TaskTextStatus> {
  const [task, setTask] = useState<string>();
  const [stopRefetch, setStopRefetch] = useState(false);
  const [textDebounced] = useDebounce(text, 1000);

  // Triggers on input text change, calls mutate once per 1000ms
  useEffect(() => {
    mutate(text);
  }, [textDebounced]);

  // Submits text task to API, stores task UUID in `task` state
  const { mutate } = useMutation(
    ["suggestions", id, text],
    async (text: string) => {
      if (!text) return;
      const res = await sendToBackground<{ text: string }, TaskTextSubmit>({
        name: "send-text",
        body: { text },
      });
      return res;
    },
    {
      onSuccess(data) {
        if (!data) return;

        // Sets the created task UUID
        setTask(data.task_uuid);
      },
      onError(e) {
        console.log(e, "ERROR");
      },
    },
  );

  // Activates when task_uuid is known(when task is created)
  // Polls the API every 2 seconds in the background
  // Stops when receives result
  return useQuery(
    ["suggestions", id, text],
    async () => {
      if (!task) return;
      setStopRefetch(false);
      const res = await sendToBackground<{ task_uuid: string }, TaskTextStatus>(
        { name: "check-task", body: { task_uuid: task } },
      );

      if (res.is_success) return res;
    },
    {
      enabled: !!task,
      refetchInterval: stopRefetch ? false : 2000,
      keepPreviousData: true,
      refetchIntervalInBackground: true,
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      onSuccess(data) {
        if (data?.is_success) {
          setStopRefetch(true);
          setTask("");
        }
      },
      onError() {
        setStopRefetch(true);
      },
    },
  );
}
```

With `keepPreviousData` addded, it returns the old data **only** after the first fetch. Then it sets to `undefined` because no data was returned from the following refetch.

Essentially, I need to keep the last data where `is_success` was true, up until receiving new data where `is_success` is also true, keeping out all the whatnot happens in the middle while refetching.

Hope I didn't make it too confusing, thanks for the help!

Comment: Adding a lot of extra complexity to support having an inconsistent or unreliable api is probably less efficient than fixing your api. Also I'd consider calling a mutation function in a useEffect an anti-pattern which is further indication that you're working against your tools rather than with them.

Answer (score 3):

Some feedback:

- you should throw an error when the fetch is unsuccessful
- `data` is not cleared just because the most recent fetch errored
- `keepPreviousData: true` does not solve your problem, it means the data will be kept during fetching *when the query key changes*. So in your example, if `id` changes from `1` to `2`, then data from `1` will be displayed to user while `2` is fetching. Consider if you really need it.
- remove `stopRefetch` from state. If you want *really* want to disable a query then set `enabled` to `false`

Your updated `queryFn` can look like this:

```
async () => {
  const res = await sendToBackground<{ task_uuid: string }, TaskTextStatus>(
    { name: "check-task", body: { task_uuid: task } },
  );

  if (!res.is_success) { throw new Error('Fetch not successful') }

  return res;
},
```